# I want to pass very long string as parameter in Asp .net core web api POST method?

Tags: .net, api, post, .net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I want to pass very long string as parameter in Asp .net core web api POST method, but when I am passing that it takes only starting few words. How to resolve this issue?

The data I'm passing:

```
{
"Stack":"  RtrnAddr            Arg#1             Arg#2             Arg#3             Arg#4               Function or address
  -----------------   ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------   -------------------------------------------------------------------
  00000000`378265ef0 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`38e97628 00000000`1efb5b50 00000000`00000000 
  00000000`0058000001 : 00000000`38e97628 00000000`1efb5b50 00000000`00000000 000007fe`ed12964e 
  00000000`38e987628 : 00000000`1efb5b50 00000000`00000000 000007fe`ed12964e ffffffff`fffffffe 
  00000000`1efb58b50 : 00000000`00000000 000007fe`ed12964e ffffffff`fffffffe 00000000`0028d830 
  00000000`000000000 : 000007fe`ed12964e ffffffff`fffffffe 00000000`0028d830 00000000`001e0644 
"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the [FromBody] attribute to the parameter in the api method?

ex: [FromBody] string value

Please see the below link. It may be useful.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/734080/How-to-Pass-a-Large-String-to-a-Web-API-Method-A-2

Comment: Yes , I have Added but still in postman I am getting error with status code 415

Comment: Have you tried with "Content-Type": "application/json" header in postman?

Comment: Yes , content type is ""application/json""

Comment: Have you tried with raw format also? Then pass data as below.{ 
  "data" : { 
    "test1": [ 
      "1",
      "12" 
    ], 
    "test2": 4,
    "test3": 7, 
    "test4": 1
  }
}

Comment: passing in raw format , but still same issue Jason value could not be convert into system.string my post method in controller is  like                                                        
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult>Post([FromBody]string Stack)
        { }

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult>Post([FromBody]string Stack)
        {

Comment: There might be an issue with the way data is passed. Can you add the raw data here?

Comment: If you are using asp.net core 3.0 then this has built-in JSON support. Try this also.   [HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] string Stack)
{

    string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Stack);
    return Ok();

}

Comment: I have added raw data in quetion please check

Answer (score 0):

```
Data you are passing has no issue. It is working. Try this please.

Create another class like this.

public class StackData
    {
        public string Stack{ get; set; }
}

Then use that class with the parameter in api method as below.

public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] StackData Stack)
```